# We are an ISV Partner that is trying to make our ISV Package on the AppExchange available for Professional Edition Orgs

Tags: apex, managed-package, isv, professional-edition

We are an ISV Partner and our Package has already passed the Security Review and is available on the App Exchange. We are now trying to make our package available for Professional Edition as well.
Before we were using some features (e.g. Approval) in our Apex Code that are not supported on Professional Edition. So we went through our code and refactored our code to only use features supported on Professional Edition. We then created a new Beta Package with those changes and tried to test if the Package works on a Professional Edition Scratch Org created from our DevHub using this config file:

```
{
  "country": "US",
  "edition": "Professional",
  "language": "en_US",
  "hasSampleData": true,
  "features": [
    "API"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    }
  }
}
```

We were successfully able to install the Beta Package on the created scratch org. We can use all UI components like LWC but whenever Apex is called we get an error like this:
`No apex action available for:` 
From reading the documentation permission to run apex on Professional Edition orgs should be automatically granted for ISV Package that have passed the Security Review.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm
To us it looks like we are still missing this permission or is testing Beta Packages on Scratch Orgs not supported? If that is the case what is the recommended approach to test Packages on Professional Edition?

Comment: I don't know about professional edition as we do not support it with our packages. Could this simply be that you need the permission to actually be granted in the profile or perm set? Alternatively, some ISV extras (such as the ability to create patch versions) must be explicitly enabled by Salesforce, and they sometimes fail to do so. It is possible this is a situation like that. You should raise a support case to ask if this is the problem. NB: testing beta releases on scratch orgs IS permitted.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I think my phrasing was not good there, we have used Beta Packages on scratch orgs for a long time. We were just wondering if there are some Limitations for Professional Edition Scratch Orgs

Answer (score 1):

Add the `AuthorApex` feature to your [scratch org definition file features](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) if you need to use Apex in Professional Edition. While standard Professional Edition doesn't have Apex, this feature will let you test your package in a Scratch Org as if it had Apex enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We tried this approach and are now running into the issue that our package exceeds the maximum number of custom fields allowed for one object on Professional Edition Scratch Orgs. From our understanding fields from a managed package should not count against Org Limits. That's why we want to test with an installed package on a scratch org. From the documentation it seems as if there are permission for managed packages as well and to us it seems like our package is missing the permission to have apex executed on Professional Edition. Is our assumption about this wrong?

Comment: @HannesSchmidt I don't have ISV access, so some of my knowledge is outdated, but I don't think there's a way to get a hold of a PE org that would allow you to treat your package as if it were already granted the additional feature that your package would have to not count against the soft fields-per-object limit and API access. You might try using a Partner Test org that you can create from the Environment Hub, available in your Partner Business Org.

Comment: If you generate a beta package version for a package that has passed security review, the beta release should benefit from all ISV "benefits". You should then be able to install it on a Professional Edition (scratch/sandbox) org without this limit getting in the way.